# How to download dependency jar's from S3 using gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

How to download dependency jar's from S3 using gradle?

Here is my build.gradle

```
group 'com.hello'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/maven-repo-bucket"
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey "${System.getenv('aws_access_id')}"
            secretKey "${System.getenv('aws_secret_key')}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('hello1.jar')
    compile files('hello2.jar')
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

`maven-repo-bucket` is my **s3 bucket name** and `hello1.jar` and `hello2.jar` is the name of my jar files that are under my s3 bucket I don't know the group id and artifact id of these files but I want to download `hello1.jar` and `hello2.jar` and put into local maven repo just like any other dependency.

Comment: They're *your* jar files. What coordinates did you give them?

Comment: @chrylis What do you mean coordinates here?

Comment: You need to organize those files according to GAV convention e.g. to provide Maven 2 repository structure.